# Angular Firebase Cloud returns incorrect data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with Angular 8 and the Firebase cloud database. If I get my user document initially it is correct. Then I call some logic which only changes some values but not all. Then I reload the user but some of the values are not correct even if they are not updated. It is really strange and I do not know why this happens. Here is my code snippet:

```
    // if the user is set return the user, if not set get user from firebase, if withRefresh is true always refresh user
    GetUser(withRefresh?: boolean): Observable<User> {
        if (this.user == null || withRefresh) {
            return this.authService.GetUser().pipe(map(user => {
                console.log(user);
                this.user = user;
                return this.user;
            }));
        } else {
            return of(this.user);
        }
    }
```

AuthService:

```
    GetUser(): Observable<User> {
        return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap((user) => {
            if (user) {
                return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
            } else {
                this.LogOut();
            }
        }));
    }
```

This is in my dashboard where I call the first GetUser method:

```
SyncActivities() {
        this.appStore.GetUser().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((user) => {
            if (this.appStore.user != null) {
                this.syncActivitiesService.Synchronize(this.appStore.user);
            }
        });
    }
```

At the end of my Snychronize function I reload the user and activities. This returns the wrong values.

```
if (i === activities.length - 1) {                                              
    this.appStore.GetUser(true).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
        this.appStore.GetUserActivities(true);
    });
}
```

On the Firebase Cloud the data is correct.

[console log correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htQUi.png)
[console log incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ2ut.png)

Comment: Please add as many details as possible. We are not sure why it is not correct either. What is the logic you are calling that updates the values? Where are you subscribing to this observable at, etc.

Comment: I added some more snippets. I hope you get a better overview now.